# Displaying Google Custom Search results inside a fancyBox(JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fancybox, google-custom-search

I'm using JQuery fancyBox. And also i'm using Google custom search(CSE) in my web page. But the search results will be displayed in a separate web page. Since i'm using fancyBox to pop up my other information, **I want to display the Google CSE results inside a fancy box**.

I tired [this](http://www.fancybox.net/howto) tutorial and it uses a method which use a `<a>` tag to load a fancy box. I can't load the `<div>` which contain my CSE results in that way though i can load some other normal div(again using a `<a>` tag ).

can anyone show me a way to do that ? (***a way to display the Google CSE results inside a fancy box***)

Comment: Google CSE wizard provides you an option to display results in an overlay window. You do not need fancyBox.

Comment: @Salman A : I can't find the 'Google CSE wizard' which you have mentioned above. Could you be more specific. It will be really helpful. thank you.

Comment: http://www.google.com/cse/

Comment: @Salman A : thanks, its true. But how can i display it in a separate fancyBox. (Because i need to customize it)